# add session datatable to a dataset

Tags: c#, session, datatable, dataset

I have a dataset and I wish to fill in a session datatable into it. how can I do it?

I do tried use ds.table.add but it throw me an error.

code below is my code to fill in the datatable.

```
Session.Add("TicketListing", ds2);
Dataset ds = new Dataset();
ds.table.add(Session["TicketListing"] as DataTable);
```

ds2 is get from database.

anyone has any idea how can I do it or anything goes wrong with my code?

your comment and suggestion is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what all the object are suppose to be.  This is my best guess

```
           string ds2 = "ds2";
            DataTable Session = new DataTable("TicketListing", ds2);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(Session);
```